# Работа с массивами в lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Как удалить значения в массиве если они там есть и добавить если их нет?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о современных браузерах, то вам не нужен Underscore.js/Lodash. Задача решается средствами самого языка:

```
var toggleItem = function (arr, value) {
    if (arr.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        var copy = arr.slice();
        copy.push(value);

        return copy;
    }

    return arr.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== value;
    });
};

console.log(toggleItem([1, 2, 3], 3));
console.log(toggleItem([1, 2, 3], 4));
```

Если же вам нужно поддерживать более старые браузеры (IE<9), тогда можно упростить себе жизнь, используя Underscore.js/Lodash:

```
var toggleItem = function (arr, value) {
    if (_.indexOf(arr, value) === -1) {
        var copy = arr.slice();
        copy.push(value);

        return copy;
    }

    return _.without(arr, value);
};

console.log(toggleItem([1, 2, 3], 3));
console.log(toggleItem([1, 2, 3], 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не JS, Java разработчик.

Не подойдет такой вариант?

```
var solution = function (array, object) {
    var isRemoved = false;

    _.remove(array, function(currentObject) {
        if (currentObject.id === object.id) {
            return isRemoved = true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    if (!isRemoved) {
        array.push(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash v4.16.4

```
function(val, arr) {
    if (_.includes(arr, val)) {
        return _.without(arr, val);
    }
    return _.concat(arr, val);
}
```

- `_.includes` - проверяет наличие элемента в массиве
- `_.without` - возвращает массив без указанного элемента
- `_.concat` - добавляет элемент к массиву и возвращает новый массив

Comment: Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте свой код, чтобы начинающим было его проще  понять

Comment: @eastwing прокомментировал